# Convert decimal? to decimal in earlier versions of .NET (C# Version 7.3)

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimal, c#-7.3

So after searching for similar questions, I haven't seen any results.

The error that keeps popping up is

> Feature 'target-typed conditional expression' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 9.0 or greater.

The code:

```
.Select(x => new FinancialStatementDto
 {
   Uid = Guid.NewGuid(),
   AccountNumber = x.Key.AccountNumber,
   Credit = x.Any(y => y.Credit.HasValue) ? Math.Abs((decimal)x.Sum(y => y.Credit)) : null,
   Debit = x.Any(y => y.Debit.HasValue) ? x.Sum(y => y.Debit) : null,
   AccountName = x.Key.AccountName
 });
```

The error pops up on
`Credit = x.Any(y => y.Credit.HasValue) ? Math.Abs((decimal)x.Sum(y => y.Credit)) : null,`

Credit is defined as `decimal?` however the `Math.Abs` function doesn't allow nullable values.

Any ideas?

P.S. It must be done on version 7.3

Comment: try adding `(decimal?)` in front of `Math.Abs`.

Comment: Are you querying a list in memory or a database through eg EF Core? Why use that `.Any()`? You may be able to write just `Credit =Math.Abs(x.Sum(y => y.Credit))`

Comment: It was already added when I entered the firm, but I'm assuming it's checking if there is any value assigned to it. I tried doing `Credit =Math.Abs(x.Sum(y => y.Credit))` but the page failed to load.

Comment: @BojanPetkovski so *are* you querying from a database or not?  If yes, which ORM are you using? That `Any()` would produce an inefficient query. In SQL, `SUM()` ignores NULLs, and only returns NULL if no values are found. `ABS(SUM(Credit))` would return `NULL` by itself. Is the *real* question perhaps how to use `Math.Abs` in EF or EF Core?

Comment: Not really sure, that I have to ask the people who built the code to get to the answer. The real question was how to use `ABS` on nullable decimal values before 7.3 version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the left side of your conditional is a non-nullable `decimal`, while the right side is `null`. There is no conversion between the two, and the language prior to C# 9 does not care about the target of the assignment being the common type (i.e. `decimal?`).

Adding a cast to `decimal?` on the left side will fix the issue:

```
Credit = x.Any(y => y.Credit.HasValue)
    ? (decimal?)Math.Abs((decimal)x.Sum(y => y.Credit))
    : null,
```

Answer (score 3):

You get this error because you have an expression of the kind `someBool ? someDecimal : null`, and C# prior to 9 cannot yet use the the assignment target to infer the return type `decimal?`.

The usual workaround is to explicitly type either expression with the nullable target type, i.e.:

```
 someBool ? someDecimal : (decimal?)null
```

or

```
 someBool ? someDecimal : new decimal?()
```

or

```
 someBool ? (decimal?)someDecimal : null
```

---

Note that this workaround is still required even in C# 9 if the compiler does not know the target type:

```
decimal? d = someBool ? someDecimal : null;       // compiles in C# 9 and above
var d = someBool ? someDecimal : null;            // never compiles
var d = someBool ? someDecimal : (decimal?)null;  // always compiles
```

<sup>(Nitpick: And by "always" I mean "C# 2.0 and above", since nullable types were introduced in C# 2.0.)</sup>

Comment: Should be noted that C# 9 also does not infer a nullable type from the conditional alone, however it can infer the type from the target so if the conditional expression is assigned to a nullable type it will work but if it's assigned to `var` it will not.

Comment: @juharr: Good point, I've clarified that.

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
Credit = x.Any(y => y.Credit.HasValue) ? Math.Abs(x.Sum(y => y.Credit ?? 0)) : null
```

Comment: The issue is not that `Credit` is nullable, it's that the conditional before C# 9 could not infer the type from the target and thus cannot determine the common type between `decimal` and `null`.